# my auto discord leveing system is giving me errors

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a leveling system on discord.py I have the latest version of discord.py I don't know why it keeps giving me errors I'm new to discord.py feel free to edit my code so it works thank you.

My code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join():
    with open('users.json', 'r')as f:
///       users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
         json.dump(users, f)



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('users.json', 'r')as f:
        users=json.load(f)
    

    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

    with open('users.json', 'w')as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id]= {}
        users[user.id]['experience']=0
        users[user.id]['level']=1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]['experience']
    lvl_start=users[user.id]['level']
    lvl_end=int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await client.send_message(cannel, '{} has leveled up to level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
        users[user.id]['level']=lvl_end
```

Error:

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The code that is giving me problems:
users = json.load(f)

Comment: Please take a look at what a [mre] is. Your question is answerable in current form, but remember for the next time. Also, could you provide full traceback?

Comment: He's a beginner, Basically, just shorten down your code so it gives you just the error, giving more code that doesn't co-relate to the error or is just extra to what you need help with is not good for other people who are either answering the question or questioning the same error.  leaving your code like that makes the format harder to look at for the people seeking the same question! So heads up

Answer (score 0):

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`
basically means that your json file does NOT have `{}` at the start, so the code is expecting `{}` but you didn't give anythong (empty file). try adding `{}` to your JSON file.